# Java graph visualization package with custom vertices for intersections

Tags: java, graph-theory, graph-visualization

I want to visualize electric schemes in Java using graphs. I would like the result to look something like this:

[image: electric scheme]

In particular: I would like the crossing vertices to look like this, one of the vertices having a little bump, so it's clear it's not an intersection of the connections.

Is there a Java library that has this functionality or where this functionality could be easily implemented?

In addition, I would like to do some analysis of the graphs, so it would be nice if the library also has some in-built functionality for this.

Comment: Not sure why do you need a "bump"? instead you can show whether there is a connection or not using a "dot". If there is no dot, there is no connection.

Comment: @SomeDude well that's not up to me, I didn't make the specification. Anyway, it's to remove all ambiguity.